# How to visualize a three dimensional hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra

In one of the exercise of Linear Algebra it is mentioned that the columns of following matrix lie in a three dimensional hyperplane $$
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
    -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
\
$$
I know that the three dimensional hyperplane is defined as $$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4x_4=b$$ But how can we prove that the columns of above matrix $M$ lie in a three dimensional hyperplane? And what should be the values of $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,b$ for the hyperplane? How to visualize this hyperplane? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As regards "how to visualise it" then if you think of the 3d space which surrounds you as going on forever in all 3 dimensions rather than being a 3-sphere, then that's a 3d hyperplane.

Comment: Then how about the other questions that I posed? for example Why they did not mention that the columns lie in two dimensional plane?

Comment: One of the key properties of a 3d hyperplane is that it's situated within a space at least one dimension larger, so your matrix represents a 3d plane but it's situated within 4d space. The $4\times4$ matrix represents the $4d$ space. Multiply your matrix by a $1\times4$ matrix and you can generate a set of equations whose solution is the set of points in the hyperplane.

Comment: You can think of any pair $1,-1$ in any as determining the slope of your plane in that dimension when multiplied by positive coefficients.

Comment: @ProducerofBS Thank you for your comment. But in your comment you mentioned that 3d hyperplane lies in atleast 4 dimensional space. However, my question was how do we know that the column of the matrix lie in a three dimensional hyperspace and not in two dimensional hyperplane?\

Comment: Show that three of the columns are linearly independent. Then they cannot lie in a two-dimensional subspace.

Comment: @FrankMoses Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $$c_4=-(c_1+c_2+c_3)$$ with $c_1$,$c_2$ and $c_3$ linearly independent, thus the columns of $M$ span a subspace of dimension $3$ that is an [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) in $\mathbb{R^4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the first three column vectors are linearly independent and the fourth vector is the sum of those three, therefore their span is $3$-dimensional.  So $(1,1,1,1)$ is a normal vector for the hyperplane, hence $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=1$ and $b=0$.